# How to create HTTP header with Kafka header in SCDF httpclient (or http-request) app?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to create a test stream like this : `time | oauth-processor | httpclient | log`.

In this stream, my oauth-processor gets a token and store it in the kafka message headers. This one works well and I get a message like :

```
[
 payload=03/19/21 13:00:15, 
 headers={
  ... standard-headers ..., 
  ...
  OAuth={
    TokenType=bearer, 
    ExpiresIn=480, 
    AccessToken=myEncodedToken
  }
 }
]
```

Then I want to put the token in the HTTP header for authentication like this :

```
{
  'Content-Type':'application/json', 
  'Authorization':'bearer myEncodedToken'
}
```

Here is what I'm trying with the header-expression property in command line :
`--headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':#jsonPath(headers, \"$.OAuth.TokenType\").concat(\" \").concat(#jsonPath(headers, \"$.OAuth.AccessToken\"))}`

but I can't manage to create a valid JSON string with SpEL.

The documentation for starter apps is very poor, as for SpEL in `SCDF` (especially when we have to escape characters) and I can't find anything helpful on the Internet

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a solution using a properties file with this line :

`app.httpclient.headers-expression={'Content-Type':'application/json','Authorization' : headers.OAuth.Authorization}`

SpEL is very confusing in SCDF...
Sometimes you need to use #jsonPath, sometimes not ...

Not sure but it seems that the comma was also breaking the expression in the command line